# Three-Way Interactions Missing in Multiple Regression Model with 4 Predictors?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression, interaction

I have four predictors that are meant to predict a variable called "quit", and I'm trying to run a multiple regression model to look at how they interact. However, when the model returns its summary, two three-way interaction terms are denoted as missing (NA). I looked at the correlation matrix and I'm fairly sure this isn't a collinearity problem. Does anyone have ideas on what might be going on / how to fix this?

Here's the image of a part of the dataframe:
[interaction_data: 4 predictors (q1-q4), 1 outcome variable (quit)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tFVt.png)

I've also tried to center and scale my data, but the issue still comes up.

```
# First, I tried to put my predictor variables (q1-q4) and outcome variable all into one dataframe & rename them accordingly 

interaction_data <- responses_vals %>% 
   mutate("quit" = participant_data$Klein_Quit_Intentions_Scale) %>% 
  rename("affthreat" = "q1", 
         "insthreat" = "q2", 
         "affbehav" = "q3", 
         "insbehav" = "q4")


# then, I center scaled the data and ran the interaction analysis 
interaction_data <- as.data.frame(scale(interaction_data))

lin_reg <- lm(quit ~ (affthreat*insthreat*affbehav*insbehav), 
              data = as.data.frame(interaction_data))
summary(lin_reg)
```

The output for the summary is below. As you can see, there's 2 three-way interactions that are missing, and noted as "NA" even though none of my columns have missing values.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9dRQ.png)

Any insight would be super appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Always read console output carefully, `"Coefficients: 3 not defined because of singularities"`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two situations where the coefficients will be NA.

1. When you have more predictors than the number of observations. ie You are unable to estimate all the coefficients. In this situation even the standard error will be NA and t-tests/p-values will all be NA. You use half plots to determine the effects
2. When there is complete aliases.

In your case, you are experiencing the second situation. Two columns that are exactly the same. or a column derived from a combination of the others perfectly without randomness. Try using  the function `alias` to determine the columns that are exactly the same:

Example:

```
example('alias')
summary.lm(npk.aov)

Call:
aov(formula = yield ~ block + N * P * K, data = npk)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.3000 -1.6833  0.1583  1.9979  4.4750 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  54.8750     0.8021  68.415  < 2e-16 ***
block1        1.7125     1.3893   1.233  0.24131    
block2        1.6792     0.8021   2.093  0.05822 .  
block3       -1.8229     0.5672  -3.214  0.00744 ** 
block4       -1.0137     0.4393  -2.308  0.03965 *  
block5        0.2950     0.3587   0.822  0.42689    
N1            2.8083     0.8021   3.501  0.00437 ** 
P1           -0.5917     0.8021  -0.738  0.47490    
K1           -1.9917     0.8021  -2.483  0.02880 *  
N1:P1        -0.9417     0.8021  -1.174  0.26317    
N1:K1        -1.1750     0.8021  -1.465  0.16865    
P1:K1         0.1417     0.8021   0.177  0.86275    
N1:P1:K1          NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.929 on 12 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7886,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5948 
F-statistic: 4.069 on 11 and 12 DF,  p-value: 0.01156
```

in the above example `N1:P1:K1` is `NA` that is because it is linearly dependent on the other columns:

```
alias(lm(npk.aov))
Model :
yield ~ block + N * P * K

Complete :
         (Intercept) block2 block3 block4 block5 block6 N1   P1   K1   N1:P1 N1:K1 P1:K1
N1:P1:K1    0         1/4    1/4    1/4      0      0   -1/4 -1/4 -1/4  1/2   1/2   1/2
```

This means that if we take `1/4*block2+1/4*block3 + ...+1/2*P1:K1` it will be exactly same as `N1:P1:K1`

```
mod_mat <- model.matrix(lm(npk.aov))
alias_coef <- c(alias(lm(npk.aov))$Complete)
cbind(mod_mat[,13], round(mod_mat[,-13]%*%alias_coef,10))
   [,1] [,2]
1     0    0
2     0    0
3     0    0
4     0    0
5     0    0
6     1    1
7     0    0
8     0    0
9     0    0
10    1    1
11    0    0
12    0    0
13    0    0
14    1    1
15    0    0
16    0    0
17    0    0
18    0    0
19    0    0
20    0    0
21    0    0
22    0    0
23    0    0
24    0    0
```